# -Chroot- Ubuntu KDE Network Manageer

Tags: networking, network-manager, kde, chroot

I'm running Ubuntu KDE through Crouton on the ChromeOS, and the network manager doesn't seem to show up (doesn't show up on XFCE either). I tried running it "Unknown Command". I tried reinstalling the network manager, then it gave me this:

```
(precise)mc@localhost:~$ nm-applet

** (nm-applet:31708): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

** (nm-applet:31708): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
** Message: Starting applet secret agent because GNOME Shell disappeared

** (nm-applet:31708): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

And now the icon appears in the system tray, grayed out, saying it isn't started. Anyone have any ideas?